# Selenium can't find any element on Trading View Chart

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, tradingview-api

Trying to export chart data for the full featured chart but selenium throws this exemption when it reaches the chart. Please help thanks.

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".button-9U4gleap button-2ioYhFEY apply-common-tooltip isInteractive-20uLObIc"}
(Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
import re
import pyautogui

PATH = "/Applications/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/chart/GZ2VoO8U/#signin")

# Sign into the page

time.sleep(2)
username = 
password = 
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="overlap-manager-root"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div/span').click()
driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('tv-button__loader').click()
time.sleep(10)  # ensure the page loads (bottleneck)

#Search for the currency pair
driver.find_element_by_name("query").send_keys("AUDUSD", Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(2)

#Gets the full size chart of the pair
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="js-category-content"]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/a').click()

time.sleep(10)

driver.find_element_by_class_name("button-9U4gleap button-2ioYhFEY apply-common-tooltip isInteractive-20uLObIc").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="overlap-manager-root"]/div/span/div[1]/div/div/div[5]/div').click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="overlap-manager-root"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div').click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="overlap-manager-root"]/div/div/div[2]/div/span/div[1]/div/div/div[1]').click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="overlap-manager-root"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/span/button').click()
```

Comment: the url you're using, I think it's not accessible to you and that's why selenium is unable to get the XPATH

Comment: The url is only bringing me to the sign in page for me to log in to my account after which I find another chart which is accessible to me

Comment: The charts don't seem to have any iframes either so I am clueless as to why the elements can't be found

Comment: Tried changin the url to https://www.tradingview.com/#signin still can't get it to work

Comment: got it, what data you exactly want, can you post it in your question?

Comment: I am trying to get data such as the relative strength index, upper and lower bollinger band and the on balance volume to name a few. I tried to extract the data straight from the chart however, it gave the same error.

Comment: Any luck? Tried using beautifulsoup but it returned me to the page before the chart

Comment: Sorry but I am still not able to understand you requirement